# JavaFX - Pannable ListView

Tags: listview, javafx, touch, gluon

I have noticed that ListView does not behave the same as ScrollPane in terms of scrolling on Embedded Devices with touch. I cannot find a way to make ListView pannable, so as to make it scroll when dragging, and bounce back when off bounds (see example).

[image]

You can simulate touching by setting the JVM arguments below.

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true
-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true
```

> 

```
public class ScrollTouch extends Application  {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception { 
    primaryStage.setTitle("ScrollBar VS ListView");

    // ScrollPane
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    VBox spContent = new VBox();
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
     spContent.getChildren().add(getLabel("Label No." + i));
    
    scrollPane.setPrefWidth(150);
    scrollPane.setContent(spContent);
    scrollPane.setPannable(true);

    // ListView
    ListView<Label> listView = new ListView<Label>();
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
     listView.getItems().add(getLabel("Label No." + i));
    
    listView.setFocusTraversable(false);
    
    HBox rootPane = new HBox();
    rootPane.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane,listView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 400, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
  
  private Label getLabel(String text) {
      Label label = new Label(text);
      label.setPrefHeight(20);
      return label;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm ..  that's a bit weird: virtualFlow (the collaborator responsible for scrolling, no ScrollPane involved) does support pannable which the ListViewSkin sets to true only if _-Djavafx.scene.control.skin.ListViewSkin.pannable=true_ ... sounds like a bug to me

Comment: an aside: don't use nodes as data in a listView that's destroying the whole purpose of a virtualized control :)

Comment: @kleopatra well, I know what you mean, but that's irrelevant with the issue. I just wanted a small piece of code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: using a simple string would have been cleaner and just as small ;)

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the same issue with TableView.  I see it was working in previous versions but been removed ? https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8112717